# Change workspace from the terminal?

Tags: release-loki, gala

How can I change the work-space I am currently on using terminal?

Using dconf editor, I have set the dynamic work-space option to false. And have 4 work-spaces as a result. I want to be able to switch between them without the keyboard shortcuts, so that a script can do those for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally achieved this using the wmctrl command.

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl

wmctrl -d
```

gave me output:

```
0  - DG: 1366x768  VP: N/A  WA: 0,30 1366x738  Workspace 1
1  - DG: 1366x768  VP: N/A  WA: 0,30 1366x738  Workspace 2
2  * DG: 1366x768  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,30 1366x738  Workspace 3
3  - DG: 1366x768  VP: N/A  WA: 0,30 1366x738  Workspace 4
```

to get to workspace 0, the command is

```
wmctrl -s 0
```

Comment: Could you please add the corresponding command to your answer and mark it as correct? For future problems?